# $push on the basis $cond in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have `Review` schema having `likeBy` array contains the id of the users who likes the review... 
I have to query it like 
case 1: If id exist the pull it.
case 2: If id does not exist then push it.
Is it possible to do in a single query???

Review Schema

```
{  
"_id" : ObjectId("5aa0f4aeb5cbb2313276cccc"),
"__v" : 0,
"likeBy" : [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it

```
db.people.findAndModify({
  query: { likedBy : {idOftheUserinLikedArray: "anyId" }},
  $push: { likedBy : {idOftheUserinLikedArray: "anyId" } },
  new : true

})
```

I am not sure if that's what you want. Let me know if that works for you.

What this will do is, if it finds that `Review` object against the property your are searching for in `likedBy` array property of the documents it will return you the updated object so you can check the `likedBy` array if the value is inserted or not.

May be helpful

And don't forget to give it a [look](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Comment: you should store `ids` of the users who liked the post for example. I mean `likedBy` array would contain documents of the form `{idOftheUserinLikedArray: "anyId"}`

Comment: go through this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/

Comment: this is a single query @AshishChoudhary

Comment: but It does not `pull` if id exists in array

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer. It will return you the full fledged document if `id` exists in `likedBy` array.  so you can check that array . No ?

Comment: that's what I have asked in question... I don't want to queried multiple times... if array doesn't contains `id` then I want to update the array with that `id` and if array contains the `id` then I want to pull it back ... these all things should happen in a single query...